# looping through json object using jq

Tags: shell, unix, jq

I have a json file which i have obtained using curl command and it looks as below.

```json
{
  "Storages": [
    {
      "Creation": "2020-04-21T14:01:54",
      "Modified": "2020-04-21T14:01:54",
      "Volume": "/dev/null",
      "id": 10000,
      "version": "20190925-230722"
    },
    {
      "Creation": "2020-04-22T14:01:54",
      "Modified": "2020-04-22T14:01:54",
      "Volume": "/opt/home",
      "id": 10001,
      "version": "22a-20190925-230722"
    },
    {
      "Creation": "2020-04-23T14:01:54",
      "Modified": "2020-04-23T14:01:54",
      "Volume": "/home/abcd",
      "id": 10003,
      "version": "21c-20190925-230722"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to loop thorough array and get id and volume values into 2 variables if version startswith 21a. No need to form another json

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes, here's a `jq` command that does both the things you want, but in 2 separate steps:

```
jq -r 'del(.Storages[] | select(.version | startswith("21a") | not))
       .Storages[] | {id, version}'
```

The first part (`del(.Storages[] | select(.version | startswith("21a") | not))`) filters out the array elements that don't have a version starting with `21a`. The second part (`.Storages[] | {id, version}`) drills and extracts the specific information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startswith` builtin function such as

```
jq -r '.Storages[] | select(.version | startswith("21a")) | {id, Volume}'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/aIlldrqOeY)</kbd>

**Edit** : Assuming the JSON embedded into a file(`Storages.json`), then you can assign the results into shell variables such as

```
$ readarray -t vars < <( jq -r '.Storages[] | select(.version|startswith("21a"))| .id, .Volume' Storages.json )
```

and display those variables as

```
$ declare -p vars
declare -a vars='([0]="10003" [1]="/home/abcd")'
```

Comment: Note that you can simply write ``| { id, Volume }`` for the last filter

Comment: Thanks it worked fine but how i can get id and volume into variables by looping through array and version should start with 21a